# Spinning an image around like spinning a coin in Java

Tags: java, rotation, awt, transform, java-2d

How I could spin an image around just as a coin would spin if you spun one on a table in Java?

Exactly like [this](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/236/2/e/Spinning_Coin___animation_by_Mantastic001.gif) Gif.

I have tried shearing using `AffineTransform`. It's not giving me the output I want though.

- http://puu.sh/48IHR.png Sheared
- http://puu.sh/48IJx.png Original

As you can see from the two images, shearing kind of distorts the image by making it larger rather than just rotating the image.

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: I have tried shearing using AffineTransform

It's not giving me the output I want though.

http://puu.sh/48IHR.png Sheared
http://puu.sh/48IJx.png Original

As you can see from the two images, shearing kind of distorts the image by making it larger rather than just rotating the image.

Comment: Could you care to post some code?

Comment: I just used AffineTransform#shear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveat:** You're not ever going to get the same result you displayed, but you can fake it

Basically, this example simple scales the x-axis from -1 to 1 and back again...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShearTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShearTest();
    }

    public ShearTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        private float xScale = 1f;
        private float xDelta = 0.05f;

        public TestPane() {

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\megatokyo.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            final Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xScale += xDelta;
                    if (xScale > 1) {
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (xScale < -1) {
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                int x = (int)((getWidth() - (img.getWidth() * xScale)) / 2);
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;

                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.translate(x, y);
                at.scale(xScale, 1);

                g2d.setTransform(at);
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now **that** is a nice screen-shot, with the animation and all.  You have outdone yourself this time.  :)

Comment: @andrewthompson You have no idea how hard it was to create :P - I think it needs a little shearing, but that can wait

Comment: I need to make anythig like that but my image is a sphere, so how I can spin it like a rotation around the axe of this sphere?

Comment: Thanks m friend @MadProgrammer I need to represent the rotation of the earth planet, I have a sphere filled with a surface which is the globe map and need to rotate it, I have this sphere traslating around the sum but I cant rotate it around your axe, if you need more details call-me inbox

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho Not really going to be possible with a single image, you could fake using something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472233/load-a-sprites-image-in-java/35472418#35472418)

Comment: thanks! Because I have no idea, but with that I have a reference point, it helped-me so much, and now I can see which I also can make a animated gif image to put it into my motor